# Tamanho do "Maximum call stack"

Tags: javascript

É uma dúvida que tem mais a ver com curiosidade, para entender como funciona.

Eu sei que se eu chamar uma função dentro dela própria indefinidamente eu recebo o erro `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

Inicialmente, eu achei que existia um limite programado de quantas vezes a função seria chamada, e então fiz o seguinte snippet para testar quantas vezes a função roda antes de causar o erro:

```js
i = 0
function a() {
    i++;
    try{ 
        return a()
    } catch(e) { 
        console.log(i);
        i = 0;
    }
}
```

Até aí, ok.
Mas ao executar `a();` multiplas vezes, ele me imprime numeros diferentes em cada execução. E algo que notei é que, executar `a();` várias vezes de forma rápida, aumenta a quantidade de tentativas antes de acusar o erro (de 20968 a 35945).

Testei em outra máquina, e a quantidade de tentativas foi diferente também.

Portanto segue a pergunta: Como é definido a quantidade de vezes executado antes de acusar o erro?

Comment: Legal a pergunta, vamos ver o que os especialistas dizem kk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não existe um número fixo.

Já notou o nome do site? Stack Overflow? Isso é exatamente o que está acontecendo no seu navegador. Cada vez que a função é chamada, o navegador aloca mais e mais memória na pilha (stack) para executar a nova função. Como a função está sendo chamada recursivamente, não há como limpar da memória as funções anteriores, pois elas ainda estão em execução, esperando o retorno das funções chamadas recursivamente.

Eventualmente a pilha ficará sem mais espaço para alocar mais dados, ocorrendo um estouro de pilha, ou em inglês, stack overflow.

No mais: o limite depende de quanta memória já está alocada na pilha, e quanta memória é necessária para alocar sua função na pilha.

Comment: Interessante. Na minha concepção sempre considerei "overflow" sendo quando um valor excede a quantidade permitida no mesmo e "reseta" voltando pro valor mais baixo, como por exemplo se você tentar somar 32767 + 1 em uma variável tipo int(short). Obrigado pela resposta.